# Changing the PATH variable for a process running as a user on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, su

I have a server application which I start using an init.d script and run as a user:

```
su $USER -c "${PLAY} start ${APPLICATION_PATH} --%prod-test >/dev/null"
```

The application needs ffmpeg, which is a special build, and is located in the users home directory:

```
/home/user/bin/ffmpeg
```

How can I add this to the PATH variable, as ~/bashrs is not called for this use. (when I use 'su user' to logon as the user the variable is there, but not for the process if I check:

```
/proc/pid/environ
```

Ideally I would prefer if it would only be added for this specific user, as other parts of the system use ffmpeg from the repos.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either run as a login shell, using `-l`:

```
su -l $USER -c "${PLAY} start ${APPLICATION_PATH} --%prod-test >/dev/null"
```

Or export the path to the process, like this:

```
su $USER -c "export PATH=$PATH:/home/usr/bin/ffmpeg; ${PLAY} start ${APPLICATION_PATH} --%prod-test >/dev/null"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, the second one is perfect!